# retrieve data from aspnet_Profile

Tags: asp.net

how can i get specific items from aspnet_Profile?

for example, i have properties — City, Country — can i get all users that live in Chicago?

i have found the way get all users with [Membership.GetAllUsers()](http://gyazo.com/52b0a322c49d845b53d0af87f5420ea8.png) and parse result, but is there alternative method?

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13747590/64334

It's a very practical solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a practical method of doing that kind of query using the default SqlProfileProvider.

If you have the flexibility to consider a different provider, the [SqlTableProfileProvider](http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples) is a little more flexible when it comes to SQL queries.