# asp.net website SQL71501 :: View: [dbo].[UsersView] contains an unresolved reference to an object

Tags: c#, linq, sqlclr, sql-view, asp.net-profiles

I tried to query the attributes of profiles table in asp.net website according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144137/how-to-query-from-asp-net-profile-properties-using-linq). first, i defined a CLR function:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for UserDefinedFunctions
/// </summary>
public class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    private static readonly Regex ProfileRegex = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+):[A-Z]:(\d+):(\d+)");

[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillProfileRow", TableDefinition = "Property nvarchar(250), Value nvarchar(2000)")]
public static IEnumerable ParseProfileString(SqlString names, SqlString values)
{
    var dict = ProfileRegex
        .Matches(names.Value)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .ToDictionary(
            x => x.Groups[1].Value,
            x => values.Value.Substring(int.Parse(x.Groups[2].Value), int.Parse(x.Groups[3].Value)));

    return dict;
}

public static void FillProfileRow(object obj, out string Property, out string Value)
{
    var x = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)obj;
    Property = x.Key;
    Value = x.Value;
}
}
```

but when I tried to create a view I got an error that the CLR function (ParseProfileString) is an unresolved reference.

```
CREATE VIEW UsersView
AS
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT u.UserId
        ,u.Username
        ,m.Email
        ,f.Property
        ,f.Value
     FROM aspnet_Profile p
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Users u ON p.UserId = u.UserId
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership m ON m.UserId = u.Userid
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Applications a ON a.ApplicationId = m.ApplicationId
    CROSS APPLY ParseProfileString(p.PropertyNames, p.PropertyValuesString) f
    WHERE a.ApplicationName = 'MyApplication'
    ) src
pivot(min(value) FOR property IN (
        -- list your profile property names here
        FirstName, LastName, BirthDate
        )) pvt
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the C# code.  What is the unresolved reference?  When you try to execute this view code manually as a query, what happens?

Comment: Have you deployed the `ParseProfileString` method to your SQL DB?

Comment: @TZHX How can I deploy it to my DB? i am almost a beginner. I compiled 'ParseProfileString' and I,ve added the 'dll' file to DB assemblies. should I do anything more?

Comment: @David when I executed it as a query, it resulted in error: Invalid object name 'ParseProfileString'